# List of iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Implementing class graph I need something like this

```
unordered_map <Node, list<unordered_set<Edge<Node>>::iterator>> graph;
```

to store adjacency list for every vertex. However, it says that `list<unordered_set<Edge<Node>>::iterator>` is not valid parameter.
How should I implemant this?

here's error:

> Error 2   error C2923: 'std::unordered_map' : `'std::list<std::unordered_set<Edge<Node>>>::iterator'` is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

I'm using VS2012 Express with standard compiler(which is c++11 compatible)

```
template<class Node>
class Graph {
}

template<class Node>
    class Edge {
}
```

Comment: Always quote the **exact error message you've got from the compiler**.

Comment: Anyway, `>>` are two closing angle brackets in C++11, but not in C++03. What compiler, version and flags are you using?

Comment: `std::list<unordered_set<Edge<Node> >::iterator>` maybe?

Comment: My guess is your missing `typename`. Is `Edge` or `Node` a template parameter?

Comment: What exactly are `Node` and `Edge`?

Comment: Yes, Node is a template parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Node` is a template parameter, you need to use `typename` when specifying a type that depends on it:

```
unordered_map <Node, list<typename unordered_set<Edge<Node>>::iterator>> graph;
                          ^^^^^^^^
```